# Laptop remains ON after shutdown

Tags: windows, laptop, power, toshiba-laptop

Running through a unique problem,

Laptop remains still on after shutdown, it happens only with windows OS, when I install Ubuntu (and do the shutdown process) it shuts down without any trouble.

Laptop Model is Toshiba Satellite P50 .

Comment: Try upgrading BIOS and Chipset.  Windows Power Manager may use the BIOS settings.

Comment: Did this problem arise suddenly, or has it always acted that way? It sounds like a Windows driver issue (ACPI driver perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes be caused by the "fast startup".  If you go to Power and Sleep settings, additional power settings, choose what to the power buttons do.  There you should be able to uncheck the "Turn on Fast Startup".  You may have to select "Change settings that are currently unavailable" at the top first.

Comment: tried all steps. still same.